# Visual Studio 2010 Log file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, logging

I wanna track visual studio activities like projects opened, files opened in visual studio ide and projects build etc. How can i achieve the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your visual studio IDE using `/Log` switch.

```
>devenv /Log c:\log_devenv.xml
```

Comment: but its not tracking user activity in visual studio

Answer (score 2):

To write the user activities into isolated shell of studio use the activitylog service which is exposed by studio. Sample is given below.

```
IVsActivityLog log = GetService(typeof(SVsActivityLog)) as IVsActivityLog;
if (log == null) return;
int hr = log.LogEntry((UInt32)__ACTIVITYLOG_ENTRYTYPE.ALE_INFORMATION,this.ToString(),string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,"Entering initializer for: {0}", this.ToString()));
```

For more details use this link [How to: Write to the Activity Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166359.aspx)